# Swift Multi-arg Selector is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, selector

Here is working code which runs fine in **Objective-C**,

```
[dataFetcher fetchDataWithRequest:authorizeRequest
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(didReceiveRequestToken:data:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(didFailOAuth:error:)];
```

It is calling both methods in **Objective-C**.

But when I use Selector in **Swift**, it doesn't work.

```
dataFetcher?.fetchDataWithRequest(requestTokenRequest,
                    delegate: self,
                    didFinishSelector:Selector("didReceiveRequestToken:data:"),
                    didFailSelector: Selector("didFailOAuth:error:"))
```

Here the method which i'm calling,

```
func didReceiveRequestToken(ticket:OAServiceTicket,data:NSData){

}
```

**I've already use solutions given on StackOverFlow but they didn't worked for me.**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The didFinishSelector is ...AccessToken:data and the method you show is ...RequestToken:ticket:data. Is this a mismatch?

Comment: @Magnas,Thanks for the suggestion,although it's not calling that.

Answer (score 1):

It`s good a bit change in your method:

```
func didReceiveRequestToken(ticket:OAServiceTicket,andData data:NSData){    
}
```

The selector is: "didReceiveRequestToken:andData:"

Your call:

```
dataFetcher?.fetchDataWithRequest(requestTokenRequest,
                delegate: self,
                didFinishSelector:"didReceiveRequestToken:andData:",
                didFailSelector:"didFailOAuth:andError:") // Make the same with this.
```

Be sure your code have this method.

Comment: have you changed the second method ? this: didFailOAuth:error:

Comment: Yes, Its

    func didFailOAuth(ticket:OAServiceTicket,andError error:NSError)    {
 
         println(error)
  
  
     }

Now...


dataFetcher?.fetchDataWithRequest(requestTokenRequest,
   delegate: self,
   didFinishSelector:"didReceiveRequestToken:andData:",
   didFailSelector:"didFailOAuth:andError:") 

Is method.

Comment: And is dataFetcher?.fetchDataWithRequest implemented also ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you are forgetting to use `@objc` in front of your method implementations:

```
@objc func didReceiveRequestToken(ticket:OAServiceTicket,data:NSData) {

   ....
```

This is required when the the target method is not defined inside of a class derived from `NSObject` (i.e., with pure-Swift classes).